# Что делает данная операция `img[52:308,52:308]`

Tags: python, изображения, numpy, scipy, pil

Изучаю питон, и никак не пойму, что делают строки:

```
img=img[52:308,52:308] 
print img.shape
```

В коде:

```
#Fit the data into a 256*256 format and save it as a .tif file
#@Sukriti Paul

from PIL import Image
from skimage import data, io, filters
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import manifold, datasets

n=10 #number of images
for i in range (1,n+1):
    path=str(i)+'.png'
    img= io.imread('/Users/sukritipaul/Desktop/D004/test_annotate/'+path)
      #Subsection of the image
    img=img[52:308,52:308]
    print img.shape
    path=str(i)+'.tif'
    io.imsave('/Users/sukritipaul/Desk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это обрезка полей изображения (`cropping`) - все пиксели по `X` и `Y` обрезаются таким образом - выбрать все пиксели от 52-го до 308-го по соответствующей оси и пропустить все остальные.

Пример в Numpy:

```
In [267]: import numpy as np

In [268]: a = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)

In [269]: a
Out[269]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

обрежем по одному пикселю:

```
In [270]: a = a[1:5, 1:5]

In [271]: a
Out[271]:
array([[ 7,  8,  9, 10],
       [13, 14, 15, 16],
       [19, 20, 21, 22],
       [25, 26, 27, 28]])
```

Фактически это обычная операция "среза" (`slicing`), которая в Numpy массивах может быть одновременна выполнена по нескольким осям (измерениям).

Для N-мерной матрицы срезы можно делать сразу по всем измерениям:

```
arr[<axis_0_slice>, <axis_1_slice>, ..., <axis_N_slice>]
```

---

Атрибут [numpy.ndarray.shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) возвращает размерность массива в виде кортежа:

```
In [295]: a.shape
Out[295]: (4, 4)

In [296]: np.arange(48).reshape(8,6).shape
Out[296]: (8, 6)

In [297]: np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4).shape
Out[297]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: А shape????????

Comment: @ИгорьБуренков, дополнил ответ...

Answer (score 1):

Вырезают фрагмент кадра размером 256x256 из, видимо, бОльшего формата, начиная с точки (52, 52)

Comment: A shape????????

Comment: shape  возвращает размеры массива . Наверное, на тот случай, если обрезка пройдёт неудачно (например, высота исходного меньше 308)